# Spring data JPA + MySQL error Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have searched in multiple sites, found few solutions but that didn't solve my problem. Can someone help me on this please.

Problem:- **Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type**

I have tried **Projections** as below ,able to retrieve data from database, but the column values doesn't associate correctly to the data member. Column values mapped to members randomly.

For example:-
**Actual Result:**

[{**ipaddress**=1, **ipaddressvalue**=256, ipnetmask=24, ipaddresspoolid=1, **unallocatedcount**=0, ipaddresspoolrangeid=10.101.10.0, **version**=174393856}]

**Expected Result:**

[{**ipaddress**=10.101.10.0, **ipaddressvalue**=174393856, ipnetmask=24, ipaddresspoolid=1, **unallocatedcount**=256, ipaddresspoolrangeid=1, **version**=0}]

My Entity Class:-

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "IPADDRESSALLOCATION")
public class IPAddressAllocation {
@Id
@Column(name = "ADDRESSALLOCATIONID")
@NotNull
private int addressAllocationId;

@Column(name = "IPADDRESSPOOLRANGEID")
private int ipAddressPoolrangeId;

@Column(name = "IPADDRESS")
@NotNull
private String ipAddress;

@Column(name = "COUNT")
@NotNull
private int count;

@Column(name = "SERVICEIDENTIFIER")
@NotNull
private String serviceIdentifier;

@Column(name = "USERNAME")
@NotNull
private String userName;

@Column(name = "VERSION")
@NotNull
private int version;

@Column(name = "IPADDRESSVALUE")
@NotNull
private long ipAddressValue;

  //setter/getters

  } // end of Entity
```

My Repository Interface:-

**Select query join multiple tables [3 tables] and fetches few columns based on given where condition..**

```
 public interface PoolRepository extends JpaRepository<IPAddressAllocation, String> {

@Query(value = "SELECT r.ipaddresspoolrangeid , r.ipaddresspoolid,  r.ipaddress,"
        + "r.unallocatedcount, r.ipnetmask, r.version, r.ipaddressvalue from ippool_service_assignment s,"
        + "ipaddressPool p, ipaddress_pool_range r where p.customerid = :cidn and "
        + "p.customernetwork = :networkId and s.serviceidentifier =:serviceIdentifier and "
        + "s.ipaddresspoolid = p.ipaddresspoolid and p.ipaddresspoolid = r.ipaddresspoolid and "
        + "((r.ipaddressvalue  <=:firstIpAddress) and "
        + "((r.ipaddressvalue + power(2, 32-(r.ipnetmask))-1) >=:firstIpAddress)"
        + " or ( r.ipaddressvalue   <=:lastIpAddress ) and "
        + "((r.ipaddressvalue + power(2, 32-(r.ipnetmask))-1) >=:firstIpAddress ))"
        + " Order by p.poolname, r.ipaddressvalue", nativeQuery = true)
List<IPAddressPoolAllocations> fetchIpPoolDetails(@Param("cidn") final String cidn,
        @Param("networkId") final String networkId, @Param("serviceIdentifier") final String serviceIdentifier,
        @Param("firstIpAddress") final long firstIpAddress, @Param("lastIpAddress") final long lastIpAddress);

static interface IPAddressPoolAllocations {
    int getIpAddressPoolrangeId();
    int getIpaddresspoolid();
    String getIpAddress();
    String getUnallocatedcount();
    String getIpnetmask();
    int getVersion();
    long getIpAddressValue();
     }
  } //end of interface repository
```

My ServiceImpl Layer:-

```
@Autowired
private PoolRepository repository;  

List<IPAddressPoolAllocations> ipAddressPoolAllocationList = repository.fetchIpPoolDetails(
                    String.valueOf(ipAllocation.getCidn()), ipAllocation.getCustomerNetworkId(), ipAllocation.getServiceIdentifier(), Long.parseLong(sfirstIpAddress),
                    Long.parseLong(slastIpAddress));
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Could you provide a repo with your code so i can try some things?

Comment: You mean code repository?

Comment: Yes, for example bitbucket or github :) @Manu

Comment: @Sven. Unfortunately i cannot share the repo due to confidential agreement. Any input/data required. please let me know  i can provide

Comment: Can you provide a data.sql and a schema.sql file? As well as a controller (with a urlmapping) were this function is called?